# why can't I store Javascript Promise in a variable and later call "then" and "catch" methods?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise

> I have understood that Promise is a special object in which javascript which helps us to deal with asynchronous tasks and catch errors which arise from it .

#### I am familiar with the below usage :

```
func_returning_promise( )
.then((param)=>{do stuff with the param ; }
.catch((error) =>{console.log(error); }
```

How ever I quite didn't like the .then and .catch used like this and so I stored the Promise in a variable `var myprom = func_returning_promise()` .

But when I call the "then" and "catch" methods like this , the error doesn't get handled at all and doesn't execute the `catch` handler.

```
var myprom = func_returning_promise();
myprom.then((param)=> do stuff with param ) ; 
myprom.catch((error)=> console.log(error)) ;
```

**Why I am still getting errored out and why itsn't the catch handler executing ?**

Has it got anything to do with the `semicolon ;` put at the end of `then` method ?

> This is not a duplicate of question [Placement of catch before or after then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013104/placement-of-catch-before-and-after-then)
>
> My question isn't about the placement of then and catch at all which the mentioned question addresses.

Comment: Try tagging the catch onto the the end of the then and see if that helps. `myprom.then((param)=> do stuff with param ).catch...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placement of catch BEFORE and AFTER then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013104/placement-of-catch-before-and-after-then)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first and second code snippets are not equivalent.

In the first one, the `.catch()` would handle any error thrown in `func_returning_promise()` *or* in the `.then()` handler.

In the second one, `.catch()` is chained off of the original promise, so it would *only* catch errors thrown in `func_returning_promise()`.

To achieve the equivalent of the first example without chaining, you would have to assign the result of `.then` to a variable and call `catch` on *that*:

```
var myprom = func_returning_promise();

var mysecondprom = myprom.then((param)=> do stuff with param ) ; 

mysecondprom.catch((error)=> console.log(error)) ;
```

Promises were designed to be chained. So why not chain them?

Comment: Ohh does then and catch methods of a promise return another promise ?

Comment: @Nateshbhat Yes, they both do.

Answer (score 2):

In your first code, you are catching the errors that occur in `func_returning_promise` **OR** the errors that occur inside the `then` callback. In your second code, you only catch the errors in `myprom`, ignoring the ones thrown in the then chain. You may do:

```
 var myprom = func_returning_promise();
 myprom
  .then((param) => /*do stuff with param*/)
  .catch((error)=> console.log(error))
```